# Get method on Spring Repository results in Insert statement

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

I'm trying to understand how a "get" method (findXByYAndZAnd...) on a Repository (org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository) fails with an ORA-00001 "unique constraint () violated".

Obviously the insert was generated from another (previous) statement, however, I do not understand what's the role of Spring AOP and the CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor, why the transaction is committed in the middle of it. We do have

```
dbConfig:
... 
    hikari:
      auto-commit: true
```

And

```
spring:
  application:
    name: xxx
  cache:
    type: caffeine
  jpa:
    database: oracle
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc: 
          batch_size: 200
#          order_inserts: true
#          order_updates: true
#          show_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: false
        format_sql: false
```

But still... it should either do the transaction immediately, or at the end, isn't it?

```
ERROR 42664956 --- [task-10] c.e.my-app.service.error.DbLoggerService    : Error saving messages : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
RootCause: 
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SIDE.PK_RMESG) violated
Stack Trace: 

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:408) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(DefaultJpaDialect.java:128) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy162.getInstanceByxAndYAndZ(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.my-org.my-app.my-component.service.impl.PartServiceImpl.process(PartServiceImpl.java:287) ~[loader-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your reproducer?

Comment: I can't share the code due to IP reasons. My question is strictly about the stack trace provided, I would love to have a short code to reproduce but I hope someone experienced with this technology can provide some light without it. Just a better knowledge of how batches works and how AOP is applied in Spring Data would suffice.

Comment: There is a saveAll which does some inserts into main table, then another saveAll which does some inserts into auxiliary tables, and within that saveAll there are finders. The question is why the finders trigger the insert.

Comment: I asked for a minimal reproducer, not for your original code. I cannot debug prose.

Comment: I did not ask you to debug code. That's my job. I think the question is clear, if you read it.

Comment: I cannot answer your question without code to reproduce it. You can either cooperate and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or simply wait for someone who by an off chance had the exact same problem as you and happens to know that exact stacktrace. Which is more probable to yield a helpful result? Decide for youself. I think it is highly unlikely that someone will take the trouble, trying to turn your textual description into an own MCVE from scratch on your behalf by trial and error. Good luck!

Comment: The problem is, I don't have MCVE! I can try to build a simple program that tries to insert into table a, b, and makes some queries as well, or I can debug the existing program and learn Spring Data to interpret that stack trace. And hopefully get some hints from the crowd here.

Comment: Use your existing real world MCVE, strip off as much as possible while retaining the problematic behaviour. In the end, rename all the classes, packages and methods to something generic and remove everything else which is IP-protected, so you can share a generic example. That way, you wouldn't have to start from scratch. This is how I usually create my MCVEs, if I am unsure how to reproduce from scratch. Usually, along the way I am already learning something, sometimes even solving the original problem.

Comment: What does your constraint refer to (SIDE.PK_RMESG)? The most likely culprit is that you have a loaded (managed) entity, and that some value in the entity has been changed. When you try to load an entity, hibernate checks all managed entities, and if any of them have non-persisted changes, it will flush those changes to the database before executing the read (get) operation. If this flush operation results in a database constraint violation, it will initially appear as though the read produced a write that resulted your constraint violation. I believe this is what Jens Schauder was getting at.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem in a stabile manner? What is your hibernate flush mode? I am operating under the assumption that your flush mode is auto. What happens if you change the flush mode to manual?

Comment: @Nathan thanks for your comments. Yes, issue had several facets and the behavior of committing data when making a query was reproduceable. The fix was to disable auto-commit in Hikari config. I'll investigate about the flush model that we follow. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any sign that a transaction was committed. Since you don't share any code we can only guess but what is probably going on is the following:

You made some changes to some managed entities.
This might be by calling `save` with an entity, or by modifying an entity that you loaded in the same transaction.

These changes don't get flushed to the database immediately, but are delayed as long as possible.

You then perform or trigger some kind of query.
This by default configuration of JPA triggers a flush of the changes and therefore the exception.

`CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor` doesn't seem to be relevant here. It just gathers some information about the method invoked and then proceeds to the actual implementation (or next aspect) of the method invoked. You can see the `invoke` method here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/b57eb85a230d3a05e45276052ef62b1249e5a0e6/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java#L128

As for AOP it is just a mechanic used for get things like `CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor` or transaction management and even the implementation of repository methods themselves to be executed.
Apart from being crucial for Spring Data itself (remember repositories are just interfaces without normal implementation) it is not really affecting the JPA behaviour described above.

Comment: I believe this is indeed the case. I turned off dbConfig.hikari.auto-commit and now the commit does not happen at that point. The first part of the question is answered: JPA flushes pending changes when making a query. I would like to reflect in the Accepted answer the role of AOP so that a proper understanding of the internals of Spring Data are explained.

Comment: I updated the answer in order to address AOP as well in the last paragraph